# Why head method is not working in swagger using docsstring in flask?

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Docstring in triple quotes is not working in the `head` method. I am using the package flassger. I am not able to use docstring in `head` method for swagger ui. However, it is working in `patch`, `post`, `put`, and `get` methods.

```
from flasgger import Swagger

@app.route('/flight/<flight_no>', methods=['HEAD'])
    def get_flight_exist(flight_no):
        """
            show Flight Existence
            This resource returns flight exist response
            ---
            tags:
              - hello
            parameters:
            - name: flight_no
              in: path
              type: string
              description: Flight_no
              required: true


            responses:
                '200':
                  description: Flight data  response
                  schema:
                     description: Flight object
                     properties:
                       flight_name:
                         type: string
                         description: name of the flight
                       flight_no:
                         type: string
                         description: flight number
                       total_seat:
                         type: integer
                     required:
                       - flight_name
                       - flight_no
                       - total_seat

                '404':
                  description: Flight not found

            """
```

Comment: `get_flight_exist` clearly doesn't return anything, so that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: this code is not whole... only docs strings is not excuted.....it does not option of head method in swagger ui

Comment: Also, pretty sure you need to fix some indentation after the decorator.

Comment: ya i am sure.... there is no indentation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HEAD and OPTION are ignored by default.

You can use

```
app.config['SWAGGER'] = {'ignore_verbs': []}
```

to pass an empty list to ignore